# Handling minimisation in Fullscreen Win32 OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, winapi

I'm trying to create a fullscreen application using Win32 and OpenGL. I change the resolution using `EnumDisplaySettings` and `ChangeDisplaySettings` and the OpenGL functions work fine. On its WndProc I handle WM_ACTIVATEAPP and detect when the user switched focus to another window, then I minimize the application's window. When the window is maximized again, the window doesn't display properly at all. What could I include to make the application work even after minimizing?

Answer (score -1):

From the question I cannot still say what you are missing and what you already have. Refer to the http://nehe.gamedev.net/. There is a section Opengl base code to setup a window in full screen and switch back to window mode. See if you can get something from there.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the tutorial is not handling this well. See http://www.gamedev.net/topic/481756-issues-with-fullscreen--alt-tab-in-nehe-tutorials/ or http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=217670